# How to safely convert a comma-separated string to an array of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion

**Edit**:

### Why this is not a duplicate

This question specifically addresses the problem that empty strings as well as any number of space characters are converted to `0` using `Number(str)`.

Take a look at the following snippet:

```js
convertBtn.addEventListener('click', () => console.log(toArrayOfNumber(foo.value)))

const toArrayOfNumber = str => str.split(',').map(Number);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="foo" value="1,2,4,-1" />
<button type="button" id="convertBtn">convert to array of numbers</button>
```

As long as the input has a proper `value` everything works fine. Now I want to make it failsafe for the following values:

- `,`
- `,   ,,`

What caught me off guard here is that `Number("")` and `Number(" ")` both return `0` (which I don't want as for my usecase I don't want `""` or any number of spaces to be considered a `Number`).

So I came up with this:

```js
convertBtn.addEventListener('click', () => console.log(toArrayOfNumber(foo.value)))

const toArrayOfNumber = str => str.split(',').filter(x => x.trim() !== "").map(Number);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="foo" value="1,2,4,-1,,, ,, 11" />
<button type="button" id="convertBtn">convert to array of numbers</button>
```

This feels awkward, I'm hoping there is an obvious and better solution which I don't see.

Comment: One thing you can do (semi-unrelated) is shorten your mapping by using `.map(Number);` instead a callback (the parameter is assumed)

Comment: @SterlingArcher Thanks for the hint, edited it into the question.

Comment: I just noticed you can also simply filter with number. `arr = '1,2,4,-1,,, ,, 11'.split(',').filter(Number).map(Number);` `// ((5) [1, 2, 4, -1, 11]`

Comment: @SterlingArcher Wouldn't that disallow for `0`?

Comment: @connexo looks like you're correct. Maybe `!isNaN` is better then

Comment: @SterlingArcher Unfortunately `isNaN(" ")` returns `false`. Same for `isNaN("")`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I think that's related, but not a full duplicate -- OP is doing irregular string splitting, not asking how to turn a CSV string into an array (also as we've found out it doesn't allow for 0)

Comment: "...which I don't want..." What do you want instead?

Comment: You could shorten it slightly by using `x.trim().length` instead of `!== ""`, if that makes you feel less awkward. I'm not sure what qualifies as "obvious" or "better".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from @KendallFrey (who is refusing to post so I'm stealing his solution)

```
'1,2,4,-1,,, ,, 11,0,0'.split(/[, ]+/).map(x=>+x)
```

You can still use `.map(Number)` but `x=>+x` is 1 byte shorter.

Results in the console: `(7) [1, 2, 4, -1, 11, 0, 0]`

Another regex solution (that doesn't allow decimals): `/-?\d+/g`

Comment: This is beautiful because it requires iterating only once.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only dealing with integers the following will also work. 0's will be kept but empty values will be removed.

```
split(',').filter(num => !isNaN(parseInt(num))).map(Number);
```

**Example**

```js
const str = '1,2,4,-1,,, ,0, 11';

console.log(str.split(',').filter(num => !isNaN(parseInt(num))).map(Number));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const value="-99,1,2,4,-1,,, ,0,, 11"
const toArrayOfNumber = str => str.split(',').map(num => num.trim() && Number(num)).filter(num => !Number.isNaN(num) && typeof num != 'string');

const nums = toArrayOfNumber(value);

nums.forEach(num => console.log(typeof num, num));
```

We use the results of `trim` to determine if we should process it like a number. If not then we just have a `string` and that is filtered out.

Comment: While this works, I don't see how it addresses the cumbersomeness I was trying to get rid of.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this via `Array.reduce` where in each iteration you check with `isNaN` for the `parseInt`:

```js
let data = "1,2,4,-1,,, ,0, 11"

let r = data.split(',').reduce((r,c) => isNaN(parseInt(c)) ? r : [...r, +c],[])

console.log(r)
```

This way you only `iterate over the array once` post splitting. Also this would keep zeros intact and just drop any non numbers.

Comment: I like this for the *iterate only once* part, yet I prefer a non-reduce solution because I find `reduce` harder to read when I come back months later.

Comment: I find it hard to agree with you that a regular expression would be an easier read that a simple array reduce with a ternary operator inside. But you are accepting the answer that works for you so can't blame you. Cheers.